# Perl regex: find second underscore and replace with a colon within a string

Tags: regex, string, perl, search, replace

I seek your wisdom on this regex that's driving me crazy.

I want to replace the second underscore with a colon. That's it.

So far:

```
    my $str = "bythepower_of_grayskull";
    $str =~ s/.*?_.*?(_)/:/g;
    print "$str\n";
```

Current output: `:grayskull`

Desired output: `bythepower_of:grayskull`

Comment: Are there only two _ in string or could be more than two ? Few other examples would be helpful for clarification.

Comment: thnx for asking. only two underscores total. only the second underscore i need to replace for a colon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the capture group around the part that you want to keep, not the part you want to replace. Then use `$1` in the replacement to copy the captured text.

```
$str =~ s/(.*?_.*?)_/$1:/;
```

And if there are only 2 underscores, you don't need the `g` modifier, since there's only one replacement being done.

Comment: awesome. that above info plus this little snippet made it all clear. thnx much!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is

```
$str =~ s/.*\K_/:/;
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer is helpful for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can capture occurrence of `first underscore + some string` and then `second underscore` and replace accordingly.

### **Solution #1**

**Regex:** `(_.*?)_`

**Explanation:**

- `(_.*)` matches the first underscore and some string.
- `(_)` matches the second underscore.

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `\1:`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yI1fF8/5)**

---

### **Solution #2**

**Regex:** `_([^_]*$)`

**Explanation:** As your string have only **two** underscore this regex will capture the **first** one from end of string.

- `_` matches first underscore from end of string. ( Second from beginning.)
- `([^_]*$)` matches rest of the string till end.

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `:\1`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yI1fF8/2)**

---

### **Solution #3**

You can also use `positive lookahead`. This is a little modification over `Solution #2`. Only thing you have to do here is lookahead for `rest of the string` instead of capturing it.

**Regex:** `_(?=[^_]*$)`

**Explanation:**

- `_` matches the underscore after it looksahead that no underscores are present till end of string. Thus mathematically second underscore will be matched.

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `:`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yI1fF8/7)**

Comment: What is the second capture group for?

Comment: @Barmar: Added the explanation.

Comment: I don't see it. Why do you need a capture group around the underscore? You're not using `\2` anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar: Oh yea you are right. That was silly mistake. Initially I thought I might replace it.

Comment: thnx much for the information. it led me to try something diff. that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the g modifier for only one replacement:

```
$str =~ s/_[^_]*\K_/:/;
```